# Evaluate Dynamic Membership using Microsoft Graph API v1.0

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-api

Currently Graph beta api has ***https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups/evaluateDynamicMembership*** endpoint to Evaluate Dynamic Membership.

is there any other way or mechanism to retrieve same membership data using graph api v1.0 ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the result will be the same but you can filter groups by `groupTypes`. You should be able to filter `dynamic` group by `groupTypes`.

Check `membershipRule` and `membershipRuleProcessingState` properties in the response.

Example:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$filter=mailEnabled eq true and securityEnabled eq false and NOT(groupTypes/any(s:s eq 'Unified')) and groupTypes/any(s:s eq 'DynamicMembership')&$count=true
```

Don't forget to add the `ConsistencyLevel:eventual` header and `$count` query parameter